# When calling an external program that writes to a file, how to redirect it to write to memory instead?

Tags: powershell

I'm using Powershell to call an existing external executable that can only write its output results to a file:

```
& myProgram.exe /outfile=tempfile.csv
```

However, I'd rather have the results written to memory instead of a temp file, because right now I have to then do an `Import-CSV` to get it back into memory for further processing. In a loop, writing and reading to disk is not very efficient.

Any ideas? In DOS days I believe I could have used the CON device file to write the output to the console and captured that output, but I can't find anything similar for Powershell (other than $null, which doesn't help me :)

Comment: What is the external program doing? You may be able to do the same thing in PowerShell ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If the external program was written to always write output to a file instead of STDOUT then I think your only option is to read the file. Since it's CSV data it probably makes sense to output to a file anyway from the external program's perspective.